# Windows Phone WebBrowserControl HTML text color

Tags: html, css, windows-phone-8

I have a `WebBrowserControl` in Windows Phone 8 where I am manually setting the html text. Inside the html, I define the body style and state the color for the text. The odd thing is that this seems to work fine when stating a color "name" (blue, red, ect) but not a hex or rgb. Am I doing something wrong when stating the hex value that it always defaults to black? Here is the code that return the string I am setting the control's html to:

```
var style = "<style>body{color:#FF3C3732; font-size:20px;}</style>";
return "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>" + style + "</head><meta name='viewport'content='user-scalable=no' /><body>" + description + "</body></html>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `opacity` CSS property and only use 3 bytes for the color:

```
body{
  color:#FF3C37;
  opacity:0.4;
]
```